# SalesForce login request packet data size

Tags: java, android, salesforce, packet

I am developing an android application which is very much sensitive on the **data packet size**.

I noticed that when I login SalesForce using the following code:

```
ConnectorConfig parameters = new ConnectorConfig("username@server.com",
                "password", null);
        try {
          Salesforce.login(parameters, new SForceLoginResponseListener());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();      
        }
```

the size of the data packet used is near **40KB**. I would like to know why the usage of data packet is so high during simple login ?

Comment: soap has some overhead, but no where near that much, exactly how are you measuring this?

Comment: If you need to improve the login time try oauth http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_authenticate.htm

Comment: @superfell actually how much data packet is used is shown by the mobile i am using this application on. I am also confused if soaps overhead is that big ?

Comment: @MartinBorthiry thankyou but i am not looking for improving the login time. I want to reduce the usage of datapacket for login.